# Undefined index: count(*) PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I'm recreating link generation function from mysql to PDO and I have a problem.

```
    $sth = $resDB->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM downloads WHERE downloadkey = '{$strKey}' LIMIT 1");
$arrCheck = $sth->fetchAll();
if($arrCheck['count(*)']){
    //key already in use
    return createKey();
}else{
    //key is OK
    return $strKey;
}
```

Everything goes well until this line: `if($arrCheck['count(*)'])`

I get the error like this: `Undefined index: count(*)`

I just don't know how to change that line to PDO. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 3):

Use an alias to refer to the column

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM ...

$arrCheck["cnt"]
```

Comment: It says `Undefined index: cnt` :/

Comment: @feknaz That's because `fetchAll` returns an array, you need to loop around the array to access one row at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Try this using alias,

```
$sth = $resDB->prepare("SELECT count(*) as count FROM downloads WHERE downloadkey = '{$strKey}' LIMIT 1");
$arrCheck = $sth->fetchAll();
if($arrCheck['count']){
```

Comment: In this case `$arrCheck` is an array so that if would break / fail ;)

Comment: Yeah I got Undefined index: count

Comment: @JonStirling, you are correct shall i edit my answer?